# How to install msi file using powershell script

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I am new in power shell. i need to install file using powershell. My msi file location is C:\Amazon\AWSCLIV2.

I have tried with the powershell `script Start-Process C:\Amazon\AWSCLIV2.msi`

When i executing the above script gets installation windows. ie; click to next to install(Displayed window) the above msi file(i need to remove this window). but actually i want, installation should works automatically when executing powershell script.

So i need to execute installation using powershell script.

Comment: This should basically work the same way as with cmd. Run `msiexec /?` if you need help on how to do a silent install of an msi, logging etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. can you give exact powershell script? i mean where to attach msiexec /? script in Start-Process C:\Amazon\AWSCLIV2.msi

Comment: No, I mean if you run `msiexec /?` by itself you will see the options, such as /quite.

Comment: i got a window when executing msiexec /? command. i don't understand the window. can you give the solution?

Comment: @notjustme can you help me?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec)

Comment: I highly recommend looking at the syntax of `msiexec`, or reading through the documentation @notjustme posted. `msiexec /i "C:\Amazon\AWSCLIV2.msi"`. The switches you use for it all depends on you.

Comment: i have tried with msiexec.exe /i C:\Amazon\AWSCLIV.msi /qn and tested with all parameters. but installation not done.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala. i have also tried with  msiexec /i "C:\Amazon\AWSCLIV2.msi" /qn command. but installation not worked

Comment: So What is the solution? is there any solution to install msi file using powershell script?

Comment: What makes you think it's not working? Running `msiexec /i "C:\Amazon\AWSCLIV2.msi" /quiet` installs it silently with no user interaction. You can see the process in task manager or when you run `Get-Process`. The solution is to use msiexec.

Comment: Try: `msiexec -ArgumentList /i, "C:\Amazon\AWSCLIV2.msi", /qn`

Comment: Also, are you using linux?

Comment: no iam using windows. When i tried with this command msiexec -ArgumentList /i, "C:\Amazon\AWSCLIV2.msi", /qn , gets pop up window(Windows installer)

Comment: @AbrahamZinala can you help me?

Comment: hai. anybody there? i didn't get answer

Answer (score 2):

I use the following to run all my msi installs from within a PowerShell script.

```
$Args = @("/qn", "/i", "<msifile.msi>")
Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $Args -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

I always put the msiexec.exe arguments in a separate variable to make the command easier to read for my colleagues who have less PS experience.  It also makes it easier to pass a variable into the argument list as below.

```
$Args = @("/qn", "/i", "$MSIName")
```

-Wait instructs the script to wait until the process you start has finished before the script continues

-NoNewWindow ensures no additional windows are displayed in the course of the process.

You can even add transforms into the argument list with no difficulty.